# Hiding Table Column in Bootstrap Table

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I created a table and used collapsed visibility to try to hide many columns from being shown. The columns still show, just they show up blank. I want it to show as though those columns don't exist. The reason the are there is there is a search box that searches through the table data. I want it to search those items but not display them.

```
<table id='example1' class='table table-bordered table-striped'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket #</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Close Date</th>
            <th>Assigned To</th>
            <th>Work Order</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>TID #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Modem #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>MHL #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Waybill #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>TID #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>ATM Brand</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>ATM Model</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>EPP Serial</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Router #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>"; // output data of each row 
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $href='"#"'; echo "
        <tr>
            <td><a href='tickets.php?id=".$row[' id ']."'>".$row['id']."</a>
            </td>
            <td>".$row['timecreated']."</td>
            <td>".$row['subject']."</td>
            <td>".$row['status']."</td>
            <td>".$row['closedate']."</td>
            <td>".$row['assignedtoname']."</td>
            <td>".$row['workorder']."</td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
            <td style='visibility:collapse;'></td>
        </tr>"; } } else { echo "0 results"; } echo "</tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Ticket #</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Close Date</th>
            <th>Assigned To</th>
            <th>Work Order</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>TID #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Modem #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>MHL #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Waybill #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>TID #</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>ATM Brand</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>ATM Model</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>EPP Serial</th>
            <th style='visibility:collapse;'>Router #</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this backed by a database? Just wondering why you would be trying to search whatever is rendered on the final page.

Comment: the php parser needs php `<?php ?>` tags to work

Comment: Yes there's a database all the $row values display. and there is <?php ?> tags but they are further up and down in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Change "visibility:collapse;" to "display: none;"

Answer (score 0):

As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility, it seems as if you'll have to use display none, instead.

> collapse For table rows, columns, column groups, and row groups the
>   row(s) or column(s) are hidden and the space they would have occupied
>   is removed (as if display: none were applied to the column/row of the
>   table). However, the size of other rows and columns is still
>   calculated as though the cells in the collapsed row(s) or column(s)
>   are present. This was designed for fast removal of a row/column from a
>   table without having to recalculate widths and heights for every
>   portion of the table. For XUL elements, the computed size of the
>   element is always zero, regardless of other styles that would normally
>   affect the size, although margins still take effect. For other
>   elements, collapse is treated the same as hidden.